# Can I have a matrix of variables?

Tags: matrices, limits, matrix-calculus

Can I have a matrix of variables, e.g.,

$$\begin{bmatrix} x & x^2 & \ln(x) & \sqrt{x} \end{bmatrix}?$$

If true, can I take the limit as $x \to c$ of a matrix?

My thought is that you can raise $e$ to a matrix power, since $e$ is a continuous function. The limit of $e$ to the matrix is the same as $e$ to the limit of the matrix, hence, the limit of a matrix is possible.

Comment: Yes, if $A(t)$ is a square matrix whose entries are continuous functions of $t$, one can define $e^{A(t)}=\sum_ k A^k(t)/k!$ and it is OK to interchange limits across the exponential. Just be cautious about respecting the non-commuting order of matrix multiplication when working with two or more matrices $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ as usual.

Comment: Furthermore can I use the definition of a derivative to find the derivative of a matrix with functions as per the example of [x, x^2; ln x, sin x]

Comment: Yes. That is also true.